# Use dictionary with checkbuttons (boxes update all at once and values in dictionary aren't updated)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to create a GUI with tkinter that includes several checkboxes. The variables associated with those checkboxes are supposed to be stored in a common dictionary (see the example below). The problem with my code so far is that all the checkboxes update at the same time when only one of them is clicked and that the values in the dictionary aren't updated.

```
import tkinter as tk
config = {"option0": False, "option1": False}

root = tk.Tk()

def print_values():
    print(config["option0"])
    print(config["option1"])

chk_option0 = tk.Checkbutton(master=root, text='option0', variable=config["option0"], onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
chk_option0.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = "W")

chk_option1 = tk.Checkbutton(master=root, text='option1', variable=config["option1"], onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
chk_option1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky = "W")

btn_Print = tk.Button(master=root, text="Print values", command=lambda : print_values())
btn_Print.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky = "W")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `BooleanVar()` instead of `False` for values of `config` dictionary:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

config = {"option0": tk.BooleanVar(), "option1": tk.BooleanVar()}

def print_values():
    print(config["option0"].get())
    print(config["option1"].get())

chk_option0 = tk.Checkbutton(master=root, text='option0', variable=config["option0"], onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
chk_option0.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = "W")

chk_option1 = tk.Checkbutton(master=root, text='option1', variable=config["option1"], onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
chk_option1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky = "W")

btn_Print = tk.Button(master=root, text="Print values", command=lambda : print_values())
btn_Print.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky = "W")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it, I'm still a bit puzzled about how my code behaved. Could you maybe explain why both checkboxes were always set simultaneously?

Comment: It is because you actually passed `False` to `variable` option of both checkbuttons, so they refers to same tkinter variable created implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to initialise the variables with `BooleanVar()` if you want to store the output of checkboxes. ( Similarly, `IntVar()` and `StringVar()` also exists if you set the off value and the on value with int and string respectively). And finally, you will have to use `.get()` function to get the value stored in it.

```
import tkinter as tk

config = {"option0": False, "option1": False}

root = tk.Tk()

def print_values():
    print(config["option0"].get())
    print(config["option1"].get())

config["option0"] = tk.BooleanVar()
config["option1"] = tk.BooleanVar()
chk_option0 = tk.Checkbutton(master=root, text='option0', variable=config["option0"], onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
chk_option0.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = "W")

chk_option1 = tk.Checkbutton(master=root, text='option1', variable=config["option1"], onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
chk_option1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky = "W")

btn_Print = tk.Button(master=root, text="Print values", command=lambda : print_values())
btn_Print.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky = "W")

root.mainloop()
```